# shouldn't the maven assembly plugin be preserving timestamps?

Tags: maven, timestamp, tar, maven-assembly-plugin

I have found that when creating a .tar.gz archive with the maven assembly plugin, the timestamps of the files being archived are not being preserved.  Instead they are stamped with the time of archive creation.  This is not the way tar behaves.

I could not find any documentation about this on the maven site and I'm surprised it isn't mentioned more.

Or am I missing something obvious?

I did a quick overview of the plugin source code and while I may be missing something, it seems like the source is all oriented around inclusion/exclusion and directory management with some provision made for permissions.  All the file copying methods filter down to a stream copy and I'm betting that once the file is opened into a stream they've forgotten all the file attributes such as timestamps, and thus cannot reproduce them.

I hope I'm wrong.

Failing that, how else might I preserve timestamps while operating in a maven environment?

**UPDATE:**

A [Jira issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-670) was opened on this.
It turns out that timestamps generally are preserved by the plugin, unless you specify the <lineEnding> tags.  These are implemented by a routine within the plugin that reads the original file, converts the line endings, and writes a new file.  It is apparently not easy to preserve the original date in this case.  They make no promises of a quick fix but some possible approaches to fixing it were discussed.

Comment: There seems to be that presumption that it should preserve timestamps. I just have never had that requirement. Maybe you just stumbled upon something new here, really :)

Comment: That's kind of what I think.  I will open a bug report with Maven.

Comment: My hunch is they'll treat it as an improvement request.